# Позиционирование

Tags: css3, css, html, html5

Здравствуйте. Есть некий `DIV` фиксированной ширины. В нем еще элементы `DIV`, которых может быть сколько угодно. Ширина и высота внутренних элементов фиксирована. Вопрос: *Как мне сделать позиционирование внутри головного `DIV` как на картинке?*

**PS**
Очень важно, чтобы головной `DIV` по высоте был на 50 пикселей больше, чем занимаемое внутренними элементами пространство по высоте (как на картинке). И еще, использование `JavaScript` неприменимо в моей ситуации.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
.main_div { padding: 5px 0 50px 5px }
.my_div { display:inline-block; margin-right: 10px }
```

Comment: Спасибо. Сработало! Только не до конца. Как сделать так, чтобы внутренние элементы выровнялись по центру, в то время как нижняя строка будет так, как на картинке.

Comment: попробуйте внутренним дивам добавить свойство **float:left**

Comment: Не. Не помогло

Comment: В принципе, не догадался сразу. Надо для размещения по центру, просто было вычислить, какую ширину занимает одна строка внутренних объектов, отнять от ширины головного DIV, разделить на два и поставить это значение для padding левого и правого. @DemoS, спасибо, идея очень помогла.

Comment: Я сам, если честно, с позиционированием не особо дружу. Но ваш вариант, как мне кажется, редкостное извращение :) Наверняка есть способ попроще. К сожалению подсказать не могу.